# Compare Enum with Class, best practice?

Tags: c#, enums

In my program I have an Enum divided in "Group" like (renamed for clarity):

```
public enum FlowSteps
{
    GROUP1_Step1,
    GROUP1_Step2,
    GROUP2_Step1,
    GROUP1_Step2,
    ...
}
```

Then I my views I check the current step like:

```
FlowSteps currentStep = ...;
if (currentStep == GROUP1_Step1) { //Do something }
```

Now, I wanted to refactor a little this kind of grouping that i don't really like, and I was thiking something like:

```
public class FlowSteps
{
    public enum GROUP1
    {
        Step1,
        Step2
    }

    public enum GROUP2
    {
        Step1,
        Step2
    }
 }
```

Much clearer, but now I cannot compare my currentStep by doing:

```
FlowSteps currentStep = ...;
if (currentStep == FlowSteps.GROUP1.Step1) { //Do something }
```

Any suggestion on how to keep this kind of grouping of my Enum and being able to compare the class without adding too much complexity?

How would you proceed?

Comment: Why didn't do this? `FlowSteps.GROUP1 currentStep =...`

Comment: Because there is a `GROUP2` as well.

Comment: What sort of relationship is their between groups? Does a flow work across multiple groups or only stay within a single one? It's all a bit abstract at the moment to offer concrete suggestions - can you flesh it out a bit more with meaningful names?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick response. Flowsteps can be GROUP1 or GROUP2 (and GROUP3 actually). Thanks

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: To every loaded view I pass a "FlowState" class that contains a FlowType (GROUP1, GROUP2, GROUP3) and FlowStep (GROUP1.Step1..2, GROUP2.Step1..2, etc). Thanks

Comment: Encoding the FlowType information a second time into the FlowStep value definitely doesn't feel right. My gut instinct at this stage would be that `FlowState` is `abstract`, `Group1FlowState` inherits from `FlowState`. `Step` is a simple `int` in `FlowState` and `Group1FlowState` exposes an appropriate method that will `//Do something` if its called and currently in state 1. But again, without being clear on how you're using these things, that could be *miles* wide of what's needed here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks Damien, actually Hofman solution works good, and as you suggest, a simple int in FlowStep works good for my needs. For completeness: the user using the program can do 3 type of "movement" and each movement has different steps and I just need to keep track of this between views (so I can reuse views for different purposes for example, with the same view, the user can, at first, select the box from where to take materials, and in a second time the box where to move those materials: Move 1000kgs of Iron from Box A -> to Box B). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a list of enums isn't the right approach here. I would use a set of classes with integers, making them produce unique numbers.

```
public static class FlowSteps
{
    private const int GroupSize = 100;

    public static class Group1
    {
        private const int GroupId = 1;

        public const int Step1 = FlowSteps.GroupSize * GroupId + 1;
        public const int Step2 = FlowSteps.GroupSize * GroupId + 2;
    }

    public static class Group2
    {
        private const int GroupId = 2;

        public const int Step1 = FlowSteps.GroupSize * GroupId + 1;
        public const int Step2 = FlowSteps.GroupSize * GroupId + 2;
    }
}
```

As you can see you have 100 steps available per group. If that isn't enough, just increase the group size. And your `currentStep` is just an `int` now.

Comment: Well, he is using enums now, so you can't derive from them either. I prefer the values to be constants, so inheritance isn't an option then.

Comment: Yes, this looks like the best solution. And it also does not add complexity. I just need to change _FlowSteps currentStep_ to _int currentStep_.

Answer (score 0):

Patrick Hofman's answer is on target.  However, if you needed to keep the enums then you could solve this by using static, readonly classes to wrap them up. This would allow you to retain a common set of well known steps that each group could contain.

```
enum Steps {
   Step1,
   Step2,
   Step3
};

static class Group1 {
     static readonly KeyValuePair<int, string> Step1 = 
         new KeyValuePair<int, string>(
             (int)Types.Group1_Value1, 
             Types.Group1_Value1.ToString());

     static readonly KeyValuePair<int, string> Step2 = 
         new KeyValuePair<int, string>(
                 (int)Types.Group1_Value1, 
                 Types.Group1_Value2.ToString());
 }    

 static class Group2 {
     public static readonly KeyValuePair<int, string> Step1 = 
         new KeyValuePair<int, string>(
             (int)Steps.Step1, 
             Steps.Step1.ToString());

     public static readonly KeyValuePair<int, string> Step2 = 
         new KeyValuePair<int, string>(
             (int)Steps.Step2, 
             "Step Two's Other Sneaky Name");

     public static readonly KeyValuePair<int, string> Step3 = 
         new KeyValuePair<int, string>(
             (int)Steps.Step3, 
             Steps.Step3.ToString());
 }
```

Comparisons can then be made against their values, and alternate names for the steps could be substituted - as with Group2.Step2 above.

```
Group1.Step1.Value == Group2.Step1.Value
```

Taking this a step further, you could then place each group in a collection of `List<NameValuePair<int, string>>` if you need to enumerate or serialize them.

Comment: Thanks, this could be a good solution too. Access time to KeyValuePair should be O(1) but maybe there a little wasting of resource for this "simple" purpose. Hofman solution work better for my suits. (I've also removed GroupSize and GroupId and using simple 101, 102... 201, 202 etc.)